# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}| = 0$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Is there a sequence $(f_{n})$ of $L^{1}$ functions such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}| = 0$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$?

I noticed that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $x \in [0, 1]$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}| < \varepsilon$$
for large $n$ and 
$$|\sup_{n \geq N}f_{n}(x) - 1| < \varepsilon$$
for large $N$,
which is trivial, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the construction is essentially like this: Take the interval $[0,1]$ and call $f_1=1_{[0,1]}$. Then take the two halves of this interval and call $f_2=1_{[0,1/2]}$, $f_3=1_{[1/2,1]}$. Now take the halves of these intervals and ennumerate them as $f_4$, $f_5$, $f_6$, $f_7$. Then take the halves of these, etc. This sequence satisfies your conditions.

Comment: For more info, Terry Tao calls this the Typewriter sequence. You can see this in Folland Real Analysis 2.4.

Comment: @Moya: Thank you so much for taking time to tell me this!

Answer (score 2):

Choose $m$ and define
$\phi_{i,m} = 1_{[{i \over m}, {i+1 \over m} ]}$ for $i = 0,...,m-1$.

Let $f_1 = \phi_{0,1}$, $f_2 = \phi_{0,2}, f_3 = \phi_{1,2}$,$\cdots$.