# The norm $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1} \to 0$ but $f_n \not\to f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

A classmate and I are studying this following question from Stein-Shakarchi, Chapter 2, Exercise 12:

> Show that there are $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and a sequence $\{f_n\}$ with $f_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $$\|f-f_n\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)} \to 0,$$ but $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for no $x$.
>
> [Hint: In $\mathbb{R}$, let $f_n=\chi_{I_n}$, where $I_n$ is an appropriately chosen sequence of intervals with $m(I_n)\to 0$.]

Our attempt:

First, I defined $I_n := [\frac{k-1}{2^n}, \frac{k}{2^n}]$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $m(I_n)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
From these intervals, the sequence of functions is defined to be:
$$f_n := \chi_{I_n}(x) + \chi_{I_n}(-x)$$
Then $f=0$, and so
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n - f| = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n = \frac{1}{2^{n}} +\frac{1}{2^{n}} \to 0.$$

But I am left to show that $f_n \to f$ for no $x$. I do not see this from my example. But does this example work? If so, why does $f_n$ not converge to $f$ for any $x$.

Comment: It's not clear what's the definition of $I_n$. What's that $k$? A fixed arbitrary real number?

Comment: Let $I_k=[0,1/k]$, then what's going on with $f_{k,s}=\chi_{I_k}(\cdot-s/k)$, for $s=0,\ldots,k-1$. Take $\{f_{k,s}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the right order.

Comment: @user39490: I think he wants an example where convergence of $f_n$ fails on all of $\mathbb{R}$, not just on $[0,1]$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162876/lim-n-to-infty-int-01f-n-0-and-limsup-n-to-infty-f-nx/) for an intuituve interpretation of your sequence.

Answer (score 5):

In one dimension, consider in order

$$\chi_{[0,1]}, \chi_{[0,1/2]}, \chi_{[1/2,1]},\chi_{[0,1/3]},\chi_{[1/3,2/3]},\chi_{[2/3,1]}, \dots $$

This sequence $\to 0$ in $L^1,$ and pointwise nowhere.

Comment: (+1) I was thinking of a very similar sequence (mine was based on powers of $2$, but that was for ease of bookkeeping). I think this example brings out the essence of what is going on very nicely.

Comment: This sequence does converge pointwise to zero outside of the interval $[0,1]$. Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I thought that the OP was looking for an example which fails to converge at every $x \in \mathbb{R}$? At least, that's what the question appears to say.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks. Well,we can fix that. In row one, we list $[-1,0], [0,1].$ In row 2 we list $[-2,-3/2], [-3/2,-1], \dots, [3/2,2].$ Etc. In the $n$th row, we list the intervals $ [-n+(k-1)/n, -n+k/n], k = 1, 2, \dots , 2n^2$ in order, and keep going. We then create $f_n$ by taking the characteristic functions of these intervals in each row in order. Not as simple as the $[0,1]$ example, but it will do.

Answer (score 0):

We will give an example in $\mathbb{R}^1$. The analagous construction in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is similar.

Fix $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take some enumeration $\{I^k_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of all subintervals of $[k,k+1]$ which have the form $[\frac{p}{q},\frac{p+1}{q}]$ for some integers $p,q$. Notice that $m(I^k_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, because for any $\epsilon >0$, there are only finitely many $n$ such that $m(I^k_n)>\epsilon$. Define $g^k_n=1_{I^k_n}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Notice that, for any $x \in [k,k+1]$ there are infinitely many $n$ with $g^k_n(x)=1$. Therefore $\limsup_{n \to \infty} g^k_n(x)=1$ for every $x \in [k,k+1]$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|k|}g^k_n$, and let $f=0$. Then $\int |f_n -f|= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|k|}m(I^k_n)$, which converges to zero as $n \to \infty$ by the DCT (applied to counting measure), because each individual $m(I^k_n)$ approaches zero when $k$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$. Therefore $||f_n - f||_{L^1} \to 0$. However, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, say $x \in [k,k+1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\limsup f_n(x)= 2^{-|k|}>0$, so $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$, for **any** $x \in \mathbb{R}$.